# Use a functions in functions.php to remove a string for template theme

Tags: filters

I want to remove a character "h" generated by code of templates of the theme.
I don't want to use templates in Child Theme for that, I prefer to use a function in functions.php to remove the string in templates that generate the character:

```
esc_html_e('h','bridge');
```

Is there a solution for that ?

More context in a template file :

```
<div class="post_info">
<span class="time">
<?php esc_html_e('Posted at','bridge'); ?> 
<?php the_time('H:i'); ?>
<?php esc_html_e('h','bridge'); ?></span>
<?php esc_html_e('in','bridge'); ?>
<?php the_category(', '); ?>
```

Comment: You would need to share more of the code used in the theme to determine whether there is a way to unhook the function that's adding the "h". Also, make sure you're not editing `functions.php` directly, since your changes will be overwritten when you update the theme.

Comment: Thak you @WebElaine, I've edited my post and I've added more code of the template,
I don't know if it's enough.

Comment: Gotcha - it does not look like you can do anything with `functions.php` or just a plugin since they didn't create a hook. You would need to go ahead and make a child theme, and take things out there.